# Vue Router navigate or scroll to anchors (# anchors)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am struggling with `vue-router` not scrolling/navigating to anchor tags (ex: `#anchor`). I have read various solutions here on Stack Overflow, but none have worked so far.

Please find below the code I am using right now, which is not working:

main.js

```js
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/docs/1.0/:title",
            component: Content,
            name: "docs"
        }
    ],
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition;
        }
        if (to.hash) {
            return { selector: to.hash };
        }
        return { x: 0, y: 0 };
    },
});
```

Content.vue (Parent Component)

```html
<template>
  <base-section
    v-for="entry in $store.state.entries"
    :key="entry.title"
    lang="lang-markup"
    :title="entry.title"
  >
    <template v-slot:sectionId>
      <div :id="slugify(entry.title)"></div>
    </template>

    <template v-if="entry.content" v-slot:content>
      <span v-html="entry.content"></span>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:examples>
      <div v-html="entry.examples"></div>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:code>
      {{ entry.code }}
    </template>
  </base-section>
</template>
```

SectionMenu.vue (Child Component)

```html
<span v-for="item in $store.state.entries" :key="item.title">
  <router-link
    :to="{name:'docs', hash:'#'+slugify(item.title)}"
    class="mx-1 btn btn-primary"
  >{{ item.title }}</router-link>
</span>
```

I have also tried a different approach, but it also hasn't worked. This was the approach:

```html
<button @click.prevent="navigate(item.title)">{{item.title}}</button>
```

```js
navigate(route){
  this.$router.push({name:'docs', hash:'#'+this.slugify(route)})
},
```

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

PS: I am using VUE 3 (vue CLI 4.5.8)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Vue Router 4, the format of the returned object from `scrollBehavior()` has changed from what it was in Vue Router 3. In particular, the object's `selector` property is now named `el`, as shown in the [docs](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#scroll-behavior):

```js
const router = createRouter({
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      // BEFORE:
      // return { selector: to.hash }

      return { el: to.hash }
    }
  },
})
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuerouter-4-anchor-links-vc73l?file=/src/router.js:503-533)

Comment: Worth nothing that this can't work on elements asynchronously added to the document (which happens a lot with Vue)

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY Indeed. If the element does not exist on the page when the router needs to query the document for it, the scroll-to-element would not work. This is true even outside the context of Vue.

Comment: You are right. Not easy to find a factorized solution for that case though.